# How to display an external website containing javascript from jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have to embed an HTML file inside a jsp . This HTML file is dynamic and has to be downloaded based on the user request. What I tried was to download the html in a directory and then display it from the jsp.

For that one of the methods I tried was something like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String externalWeb = "external";
    String externalWebValue = request.getParameter(externalWeb);
    _saveUrl(externalWebValue);
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pathToExternal/external.html"));
         String str;
         while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
             contentBuilder.append(str);
         }
         in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    String content = contentBuilder.toString();
    String page = content;
    request.setAttribute("page", page); 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/web/external.jsp").forward(request, response);     

    }


private void _saveUrl(String externalWebValue) {      
    try {
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("pathTo/external.html");
        URL url = new URL(externalWebValue);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            outputFile.println(line);
        }
        outputFile.close(); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

I tried to read directly from the webpage. But same problem , the javascripts don't work and the page content is not loading up.

But when I just click the downloaded html everything is working as it should, but when I am importing it in jsp nothing works. How can I fix this?

Tried to include it in the jsp like this:

```
<%@ include file="/web/external.html" %>
```

Still no luck. What is the best way to do this without using iframe? (iframe is not supported by the websites that I plan to render)

Comment: Did you try using a `<script>` block?

Comment: @killjoy What is `<script>` block?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp

Comment: @killjoy How is that going to help? That is just js. I need to render the entire website inside our jsp. Not only the scripts. And the website is dynamic and can be any website.

Comment: Oh, I thought you said JS, not JSP. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem was adding this in the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<html>
   <head>
      <title> Tag Example</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <c:import var = "data" url = "${page}"/>
      <c:out value = "${data}" escapeXml="false"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Added this in the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("page", externalWebValue);
```

Used the `c tag library` and had to use `escapeXml="false"` to make this work.