# Render third party website using servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

If we had to render a website like this what would be the best approach? Can anyone suggest please.

[How to display an external website containing javascript from jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936505/how-to-display-an-external-website-containing-javascript-from-jsp/74658846)?

I am just given the target URL gateway and nothing else

Comment: Did you try forwarding from your Servlet to a JSP containing a <c:import>?

Comment: You are given the target URL. What are your requirements? Please explain what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Supposed to load the third party website in an iframe . we created a gateway for that end point . That gateway URL doesnt do client side rendering and we are unable to load the page within the iframe . looking for server side rendering options of that URL.

Comment: I guess I don't understand enough about server side rendering to help you.  An iframe  takes a URL and it is the browser that makes the request to that URL. So, I don't understand what you are saying about your inability to load the page "within the iframe".

Comment: The target URL is in a different network/ cluster , so we are looking for something like a portlet bridge or a similar approach that would load the page on behalf of the browser and render it.

Comment: To get some help, you should create another question with the tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-rendering

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342702/14790684) what you want? if yes be aware that the hosted website must set [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to [SAMEORIGIN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#SAMEORIGIN).

Comment: Iframes render in the browser and it doesn't work when the target and source are in different k8 clusters. That's why I'm looking for server side rendering

Comment: `HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://example.com");
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml()); 
   request.setAttribute("result", doc.html());");`
I was able to hit the target and retrieve the page contents like above. I also have to download the styles and scripts along the action tied to every link. Is there any means I can achieve this ?